# Why can I not find good results of my issue until I post a new question?

Tags: support, feature-request, related-questions

On several occasions I have something I need to know. I search for it on Google and Stack Overflow separately, but I cannot find a good answer.

So I go ahead and post it here on Stack Overflow.

I look though the "Questions that may already have your answer" and still cannot find an answer.

When I post it I look at the posts under "Related" and there I can find my question.

Is there a different system for searches and pre-post results than the Related field?

Is it possible that the Related field looks at he entire post to find matches while the others only look at the title?

It is fine to me as long as I find an answer, but I don't like posting a duplicate question because I cannot find the answer before posting.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what (new) [tag:feature-request] you actually asking for.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool

Comment: Sorry, I had a lot of problems posting this question as I could not find tags that would be accepted and it would not let me ask without tags I have had several requests from moderators not to add tags which match my title, so what it the points of tags? Anyway, a feature request would be to do a hidden question that is private so I can see the Related field get populated and then cancel the question if needed.

Comment: Thanks gnat, exactly why I am asking as I could not find that question before.

Comment: Also, that reply focuses the "This question has already been answered" when typing a new question. I do look through that and still Find the Related section to be much better.

Comment: I've observed this in the past, myself. As great as many features on the site are, the main search isn't the best. Both Google and the question box seem to be better.

Comment: Thank you for actually paying attention to that box instead of creating duplicates!

Comment: My experience has been that the list presented while you edit your question is far better than the "related" list after it's posted.  In fact, on several occasions I've started to enter a question just to get at that list.  But you are correct that both are far better than what you find with the "search" window.

Comment: (And the absolute worst list of "dupes" is the list you're presented with when you go to close a question as a dupe.)

Comment: I've only asked one question on my main user profile. That question was a duplicate. If I would had known it was a duplicate (I tried searching for quite a while, I swear) I wouldn't had asked it at all - I tried and searched so much but didn't find anything relevant, until another user posted "possible duplicate of" comment. Which, frankly, was a nice catch...

Comment: Related: [Why is the Stack Overflow search not that effective and we have to use Google?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268145/why-is-the-stack-overflow-search-not-that-effective-and-we-have-to-use-google)

Comment: Irony: You write a rant (not really a rant, but you know...) about StackOverflows search and asks a question, finds the answer to your rant afterwards. ahahaha

Comment: I would add that [dupes are not bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). At least they have bright sides. IMO you can ask and close it as a dupe yourself. Maybe your formulation of the question will help someone else find the answer in the future.

Comment: @Palec - Yeah, the occasional dupe isn't bad.  They get annoying when the same question is repeated daily, however.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past accidentally.  After searching diligently for a Q&A on The Stack, I give up and post my own question.  Usually, if it is a dupe, it is closed within minutes with a pointer to the one I want.  I then follow-up and delete my original question to clean up litter.

This isn't ideal, but part of the nature of "search".  Sometimes, my technical terminology is not correct for a particular data structure, algorithm, or language, so I use a wrong or out-dated term.

Most of my co-workers are non-native in English and are frequently (and understandably) stumped by this issue.  Their native language uses a different way to express a concept.  Once through the native translator (in their brain), their English terminology doesn't work quite right in a search engine.  However, when you are talking with them face-to-face, their idea is immediately obvious.  Blame it on the magic of our innate natural language processing capabilities.