# Why is the Stack Overflow search not that effective and we have to use Google for searching Specific question and answer?

Tags: discussion, search, user-experience

As of April 2014, Stack Overflow has over **2,700,000** registered users and more than **7,100,000** questions [(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) and is probably the world's best technical question-answer website where 92% of the questions are answered, in a median time of 11 minutes.

Why is its search for users and finding related questions not that much effective?

If you find a person by [first_name]space[last_name] it will search! But [last_name]space[first_name] will not give you the desired result!

And for the questions I am sure no one is using that search-box that is situated on the header!

Comment: It's not optimized for searching people, and it shouldn't be. This isn't facebook; search for the content, not for the author.

Comment: @l4mpi while that may be true, it's also still true that the search box kinda sucks for searching for questions... never bothered me particularly much though as Google works just fine.

Comment: Google is better at finding the results you want becauce they have a lot more experience in search than SE does. Setting up a good search engine is hard.

Comment: Searching is definitely not what it used to be. I vaguely remember an announced shift a while back. Since then I feel that search doesn't OR the words, but ANDs them - but this is just a guess. Right now, "named queries vs citeria api" does *not* find an article with the almost exact name (no results at all, in fact) Google does, in first place. Something is not right here...

Comment: @Stijn: Its just that it worked a lot better a while back. Ok, one had to skim through a few pages, but at least I would get a relevant amount of hits :(

Comment: @Louise you have a typo in there, *citeria* should be *criteria*. It's possible to take spelling errors into account, but perhaps they have a reason to not do that.

Comment: Oh god. Okay. I can understand, that it is hard to take spelling into account. But this is also what makes the ANDing of all strings so fatal - I don't even see anything on named queries because of that missing r in Criteria... But given the answer below and other comments, seems like I'll have to ask Google when I want to search SO. Weird.

Comment: Why is google better than bing, which in turn is probably better than the SO search? Search on this kind of scale is hard.

Comment: @Joe Dunno I just can never find anything on Bing but I can on Google

Comment: @Sammaye The question what rhetorical, but I'll elaborate. Google has done search forever, without search, there'd be no Google, on the other hand, Microsoft haven't, without Bing, there'd still be a Microsoft. Getting a great search to work is hard and takes time.

Comment: @Joe though Bing uses the same bot and indexing tactics as Google if not somewhat more aggresive, not only that but they have (or had) roughly the same man power on trying to make it good, and even did more aggresive marketing of it than Google did at times. They act(ed) as though MS depended on it. Google just know hows to do search whereas MS tries but just fails, much like quite a few of the things they do recently.

Comment: @Sammaye ... you missed the point of my comments.

Comment: @Joe no I got them, I was making the counter point that MS put in as much if not more effort than Google and at the end of the day they still are not as good. As such it isn't solely implied that because Google searches for its main income that its man power and resources in this area are great enough to keep it ahead, more that it is just very good

Comment: @Sammaye my point was Google has been doing it for longer. All of this what supposed to be rhetorical, I'm sorry you've read into it this much.

Comment: @Joe with how search has changed so dramatically I do not believe any of the old rules of search engines still applies except for the base implementation in code, of which MS was able to quickly copy. Searching is not an old mans game, it is a young boys.

Comment: @Joe I mean Yahoo has been doing it longer than Google but are they better?

Comment: @Joe I mean with your logic you could say, "MySpace came before Facebook" as such MySpace is undoubtly better and more established, of course reality will tell you it is not, Facebook ate it alive. The internet is always shifting and just because you were here first does not mean someone else cannot come along and steal your thunder, the real question is whether or not someone actually can, i.e. when Facebook stole MySpace's thunder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use the [advanced search features](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) built in to Stack Overflow every day, so the site search does serve some purpose. If I'm just looking for the answer to a programming problem that I'm facing, I default to Google. Google already indexes Stack Overflow extensively, and a bunch of other sites too. This is why 90% of site traffic comes from Google. It's intended to be the front-end to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wonder if Google knows that it was intended to be the front-end for SO? ;-)

Comment: @KenWhite Google is the front-end for most of the web, I guess. `=]`